# Round Values Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

> I want to round the following value 58.53658536585365853700 to 58.89 in postgresql
>
> I have try this select round(58.53658536585365853700,2) but its not working.
>   Any advice please?

Comment: why you want it to be 58.89 and not 58.54?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=004faabe5507eabcfba7a2cad2777bbd

Comment: Hello I want the following output 58.89 from this value 58.53658536585365853700

Comment: seems like a questuion for alt.math :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT round( CAST(float8 '58.53658536585365853700' as numeric), 2);
```

Output:

```
round
numeric
-----
58.54
```

Note: Please provide the tag of which version of postgresql.

Tested on PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: Hello I want the following output 
58.89
from this value
58.53658536585365853700

Comment: @KAN, Or you want `.89` for whatever values comes after decimal point?

Comment: precious assumption :)

Answer (score 0):

postgresql does not haw a simple way to round to the nearest multiple of 1.51

(I'm guessing that's what you want)

but you can do it like this:

```
select div(58.53658536585365853700 +0.755 , 1.51)* 1.51
```